# Can I have some assistance in proving this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

We are asked to prove the following integral;

$\int_0^x(\int_0^tf(u) du) dt=\int_0^xf(u)(x-u)du$

I know that we have to use integration by parts which when we differentiate a function will help us use the fundamental theorem of calculus. I just don't know when and were to apply this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first step: $\int_0^x(\int_0^tf(u)\mathrm{d}u)\mathrm{d}t=[t(\int_0^tf(u)\mathrm{d}u)]_0^x-\int_0^xt\mathrm{d}(\int_0^tf(u)\mathrm{d}u)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is analogous to the summation

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^i f(j)
&=\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=j}^n f(j)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n f(j)\sum_{i=j}^n 1\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n f(j)(n-j+1)\\
\end{array}
$

Here

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^x(\int_0^tf(u) du) dt
&=\int_0^x\int_u^xf(u) dt du\\
&=\int_0^xf(u)\int_u^x1 dt du\\
&=\int_0^xf(u)(x-u) du\\
\end{array}
$

The change in the
order of integration
follows from the fact that
$0 \le t \le x
$
and
$0 \le u \le t$
is the same as
$0 \le u \le x$
and
$u \le t \le x$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are doing here. I haven't seen this summation before.